# Angular-Material - Bug with Themes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, material-design

I have recently stumbled upon [Angular-Material](https://material.angularjs.org/#/). However It seems like the theme files are not being automatically included by the base angular-material.css file.

Therefor I must manually include every color theme that I would like to use...

If anyone has experience with this do you know if this this a bug or is this intentional.

Here is a link to the code I am using. When the page is ran, all of the progress-circular items that have a md-theme applied to them that is not default are not loading. The CSS files located at angular-material/themes/ are not being automatically loaded.

[HTML Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/800fd935f51264f15bc5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intentional.  Angular-Material is meant to be modular, and meant to allow the developer to control as much as possible the amount of data transfer they are willing to put into their application.  The color themes are one of the many optional components.

From [using themes](https://material.angularjs.org/#/Theming/02_using_themes):

> To use other themes and override parts [or all] of the default theme, you must include those extra theme stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks, I after giving it some thought I figured that the themes were modular, allowing you to choose the theme you would like. Thanks for the quick response.